# FOSUserBundle : handling different types of user

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm starting a new project, using a symfony2 architercture and the usefull FosUserBundle to handle my users.

In my application, i have 2 different types of users, which are : User and Entreprise.

I created a Userform (with embedded form in it).
Now i want to create a EntrepriseForm (with a different embedded form) but i'm stuck, due to FosUserConfiguration allowing only 1 registration form type.

If it can helps, here is how my config.yml looks like :

```
fos_user:
db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
firewall_name: main
user_class: Digin\UserBundle\Entity\User
registration:
    confirmation:
        from_email: # Use this node only if you don't want the global email address for the confirmation email
            address:        xxx@xxx.org
            sender_name:    xxx
        enabled:    true # change to true for required email confirmation
        template:   FOSUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig
    form:
        type:               mybundle_user_registration
        handler:            fos_user.registration.form.handler.default
        name:               fos_user_registration_form
        validation_groups:  [Registration]
```

Any idea about how i should do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your place I will add a new Role in your `security.yml`(remember to start it with `ROLE_` symfony ignores other roles). Then add the Listener `InteractiveLoginListener` to do some extra stuff redirections after login on diffrent roles.  And then add [JMSSecurityExtraBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle) That will help you to validate the access in accions and controllers just by annotations:

```
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\PreAuthorize;

class MyService
{
    /** @PreAuthorize("hasRole('A') or (hasRole('B') and hasRole('C'))") */
    public function secureMethod()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Look at the documentation: http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/installation